# Where is the local database cache in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-sync-framework

I want to to use the Microsoft sync framework With visual studio 2010 and Microsoft sql server 2008 to create local database cache

But I didn't find the "local database cache" in visual studio 2010 as in visual studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

In the add new item dialog it is available under the "Data" grouping.  Here is a MSDN walkthrough on adding it to an existing project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882690.aspx.